# Python: A standard skeleton seed for initiating standalone projects

Tags: python, architecture

In Scala I can use the following command (using Scala build tool), to get an initial project that has a pretty much standard skeleton:

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

This saved me loads of headache when it comes to clean code and initial structure of the project.

I want to achieve the same thing with Python, is there a way, a “seed” I can use, that pretty much sums up the standard skeleton for a python project? My criterias are:

1. Config files: Any files that could sums up the dependencies, for tests specifically coverage test and coverage report generation.
2. Source: the source folder for source files.
3. Test: For unit, integration and property-based tests.
4. Manageable build  tool:  a build I can use to create doc,  compile,  test,  and run.

I also asked myself, what are the big open source projects in Python look like. None, I mean none, look the same in terms of structuring the code. I looked at Tensorflow, Scikit, Zulip, and Keras on their Github pages.

Comment: Do you mean something like this cookiecutter template? https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage

Comment: that one has config files, source, test files as well as a build tool. If you want something more minimal you could check out https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter#python for a list. In case this works, please let me know and I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: @aadibajpai sounds good, as far as it is mature enough.  Also could you add how to add run app, tests and get the coverage reports for them?

Answer (score 1):

[Cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter#python) should work in this situation. It's a command-line utility to set up a project from a template. You can install it by `pip install --user cookiecutter`.

You can use a variety of templates, from a [full blown Python package](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage) to a [minimal pip installable project](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-pipproject).

Take a look [here](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage#quickstart) in order to see how to set up tests, CI, coverage reports, documentation etc.

Full documentation: https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html